# Large amount of text based documents to index and make searchable via an web or desktop interface, what should I consider?

Tags: mysql, ruby, search, text, documents

I have a large amount of text based documents (EDI Files, iDocs, etc) that I would prefer to make searchable via a web based interface or desktop interface. I looked into a few options like full text search w/mysql and Sphinx.   However, I wanted to see if there was something like a google desktop search but for multiple users.  I'm open to anything, suggestions appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

By hosted do you mean like this?

http://indextank.com/

Answer (score 1):

There's been a couple of questions on SO about this.

See: [Google-like Search Engine in PHP/mySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/502238/google-like-search-engine-in-php-mysql)
And: [Integrating search on a website where the backend is MYSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197999/integrating-search-on-a-website-where-the-backend-is-mysql)